# Actionbarsherlock cannot be rename

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am running `GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock` which is an Eclipse project. On import,   How do I  rename this file located below.

Every time I am manually renaming the file, the problem is existing when I am building the project it keeps the file recreated.

Here are the files:

> Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Failed to
>   crunch file
>   C:\Users\rtyJa\Desktop\GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock\googleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\11.0.2\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png into
>   C:\Users\rtyJa\Desktop\GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock\googleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png

Comment: And where you actually renaming it?

Comment: C:\Users\rtyJa\Desktop\GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock\googleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\11.0.2\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png

Comment: It seems you're renaming it inside build which is generated by studio that's the reason you are getting the same name again& again.

Comment: I've search the whole project including the dependencies but I can't find common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png

Comment: Try moving your project one level up in the path hierarchy, Windows at time shows  this error because of long file path